# Adding user before app actually start

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to add a user for the first time app is opened. That adding response back to me with a some sort of password, what we call Access Token. The token is using to reaching the API services.

Anyway, beside that story, what my problem is for the first time app open, I can add the user and get the token and I saved it as NSUserDefault, but I can't reach to API Services since it tries to reach services with null. After refreshing or reopening the app or switching another view and back that view will solve the issue. But just for the first time, it can't reach the service.

The problem is here, obviously, when the app opens for the first time, before the adding operation is finished, I try to reach to service what cause it to stay null. So here is the code I have:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Adding user.
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; // User informations.
    NSString *accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"accessToken"];
    if(accessToken == nil)
        [APIClient AddUser];

    //Adding the inital viewController.
    UIViewController *vc = [self viewControllerForSegmentIndex:self.typeSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex];
    [self addChildViewController:vc];
    vc.view.frame = self.contentView.bounds;
    [self.contentView addSubview:vc.view];
    self.currentViewController = vc;
}
```

Don't hang up with what I'm doing while adding the initial viewController, rather than that please just see what happens there as I add the user and then initialize the viewController. 
Being asynchronous is the problem, so I'm looking a way to adding the user before the app actually started or launched.

I'm not sure in this case if I have to add the user in `application:didFinishLauncingWithOptions`, but I don't think so that is the problem.

Comment: Please remove your image and replace it with a code block.

Comment: I would like to but it rather in this way. Because I'm on windows but I rent a mac which is a remote connection. If it is really necessary I can give it a try, but the connection is so slow that I can do in like 10 15 min, which is a total pain. Hope, not being a long code can convience you. Again, sorry.

Comment: It is voted up. So I'm adding as soon as possible.

Comment: I think that you need to fire synchronous call for Access token rather then async one - It should be fast, and your app will not work without one.

Comment: I see your point. Yeah, the way you told is what I need. So, how about firing synchoronous call? Can u show me @NickCatib how to do or do you recommend me to search for it, because that is something I really do not know.

Comment: Do you use any library for comumunication with server?

Comment: Yes, I use AFNetworking. I did forget to mention that sorry. I will add to question right away.

Comment: I just realized better one, will post it with an answer

Comment: Yeah it will be better, so I can accept as an accepted answer if it works.

Comment: If this is a `NSUserDefaults`-stored property, and your app needs it "universally" to function, it seems to make more sense to start this as an asynchronous request in the AppDelegate, than as part of your view loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so the first thing I would do is extract token related code to the function in view controller. Let's call it tokenReceived:

```
-(void) tokenReceived{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; // User informations.
    NSString *accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"accessToken"];
    if(accessToken == nil)
        [APIClient AddUser];

    //Adding the inital viewController.
    UIViewController *vc = [self viewControllerForSegmentIndex:self.typeSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex];
    [self addChildViewController:vc];
    vc.view.frame = self.contentView.bounds;
    [self.contentView addSubview:vc.view];
    self.currentViewController = vc;
}
```

In the view did load add the following:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
        selector:@selector(onGetToken) 
        name:@"getToken"
        object:nil];
```

then add the new method:

```
- (void) onGetToken
{
   [self tokenReceived]
}
```

and, ofcourse, when you get the token ( in app delegate or wherever you retrieve token ) send notification to observer:

```
// your code, saving to nsuserdefualts etc.
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
        postNotificationName:@"getToken" 
        object:self];
```

Explanation: It is a bad practice to block main thread with network - your app will not respond to any of the events and if you don't have 3g or wifi - you are stuck. User experience is bad, and that will drive users away.

On the other hand, this will open user screen, and you can put loader if you want till you notify the view controller that you actually got something. This way you will keep async nature of network and still refresh UI when you get one. If you are concerned that you will get token before opening view controller, you can add `tokenReceived` to view did load as well.

One more thing, you can send NSNotification with the object, and get one from NSNotification object, but in this case you just need to be notified that something happened, you don't need that data.

Comment: I really loved what you suggested me. It's great, thanks a lot. I just have one quick question if it is okay. I am confused at how I can understand whether I got the token or not so that I can send notification to observer.

Comment: Sure thing - I assume that in your app delegate you call service to get token - In the completion block you send notification to the observer that you got token. Simple as that. Send notification will notify all listeners that something happened and as I mentioned in the end of the answer right now we don't need anything from notification, but later in the app you can send that get token failed or something like that and handle these cases as well.

Comment: Yeah I was just realized that and was writing I got it sorry for asking. Thanks a lot Nick, I will try it right away. Many thanks. It is really simple just sending a notification when I retrieve the token.

Comment: It did not only help me, it also give a huge of a great idea. I did know the notification center, but because I'm new I suppose, they do not come to my mind to be honest. Anyway, that was a great effort and an answer. Much appreciated.